# React with chart js, labelling problems in multiple datasets for doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using `react-chartjs-2` for visualizing data.

I want to make a nested doughnut chart. 
https://jsfiddle.net/moe2ggrd/152/ this link shows how I want to visualize two different datasets.

Above example shows that if I use `tooltip` to label each data, it creates nested doughnut chart with correct name. However, when I try to make it work in my project, it only shows one doughnut chart.

Below is my render function for rendering doughnut chart.

```
render() {
  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [1, 2, 3],
        labels: ["category1", "category2", "category3"],
        backgroundColor: [                
          "#79CAF2",
          "#80DEEA",
          "#A5D6A7",
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [            
          "#31B2F2",
          "#00BCD4",
          "#4CAF50",
        ]
      },
      {
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        labels: ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3", "sub4", "sub5"],
        backgroundColor: [                
          "#79CAF2",
          "#80DEEA",
          "#A5D6A7",
          "#C5E1A5",
          "#FFF59D",
        ],
        hoverBackgroundColor: [            
          "#31B2F2",
          "#00BCD4",
          "#4CAF50",
          "#8BC34A",
          "#FFEB3B",
        ]
      },
    ]
  };

  const options = {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var index = tooltipItem.index;
          return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
        },
      }
    }   
  }

  return (
    <div className="h100per_200pix w100per margin_top_50">
      <DoughnutChart data={data} options={options} ref="chart" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this is screenshot of graph.
[image]

Why doesn't it render two graphs? any suggestions ?

--- Edit

I also have tried not having `tooltips` at all. In this case, two doughnut chart are rendered correctly but each label for data becomes undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a different label for each chart :

```
datasets: [
  {
    label: "chart1",
    data: [1, 2, 3],
    labels: ["category1", "category2", "category3"],
    backgroundColor: [                
      "#79CAF2",
      "#80DEEA",
      "#A5D6A7",
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [            
      "#31B2F2",
      "#00BCD4",
      "#4CAF50",
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "chart2",
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    labels: ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3", "sub4", "sub5"],
    backgroundColor: [                
      "#79CAF2",
      "#80DEEA",
      "#A5D6A7",
      "#C5E1A5",
      "#FFF59D",
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [            
      "#31B2F2",
      "#00BCD4",
      "#4CAF50",
      "#8BC34A",
      "#FFEB3B",
    ]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the first dataset being copied over the other dataset because the library cannot identify the difference between the two. And that is because there is no specification of unique keys (either **key** or **label**) for them.

While working with multiple datasets in the *react-chartjs-2* library, the library needs to track the changes in the dataset series at any event that triggers re-rendering of the chart (such as tooltips, updating charts on onClick events, etc.).

In such cases, you can do one of the following:

- Add the `label` property on each dataset (by default, the library treats this as the key to identify the datasets.). These labels should be unique for each dataset.

```
     render() {
          const data = {
            datasets: [
              {
                label:"chart1",
                data: [1, 2, 3],
                ...
              },
              {
                label:"chart2",
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                ...
              },
            ]
          };
           
          ...
        
          return (
            <div className="h100per_200pix w100per margin_top_50">
              <DoughnutChart data={data} options={options} ref="chart" />
            </div>
          )
        }
```

- (Recommended) Add the `key` property on each dataset that specifies a
  unique string. Add `datasetKeyProvider` prop to the chart component.
  Then pass a function to the `datasetKeyProvider` prop that returns the unique key of each dataset.

```
     render() {
          const data = {
            datasets: [
              {
                key:"D1",
                label:"chart1",
                data: [1, 2, 3],
                ...
              },
              {
                key:"D2",
                label:"chart2",
                data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                ...
              },
            ]
          };
           
          ...

          getDatasetKey = (d) => {return d.key};

          return (
            <div className="h100per_200pix w100per margin_top_50">
              <DoughnutChart
                   datasetKeyProvider={this.getDatasetKey}
                   data={data} options={options} ref="chart" />
            </div>
          )
        }
```